# Who to use for email hosting?

Tags: email, ssl, hosting

I'm curious if anyone has used Rackspace for email hosting:
http://www.rackspace.com/apps/email_hosting/rackspace_email

Or if anyone has other companies they've tried (must have SSL) and are happy with.

Thanks,
Ryan

Comment: Does anyone have suggestions on where I can ask this question? Nevertheless, I am interested in what people have to say about this.

Answer (score 1):

Gmail (part of Google Apps) offers SSL and has the - by far - best spam protection. At $50/user/year it is also priced very reasonably.

Actually, if you are less then 50 users use the free version of Google apps, there is almost no difference. Only significant difference:

- paid 20 GB, free 7 GB disk space
- paid 2000/emails day, free 500 email/day (roughly!)

I did not notice any difference in uptime over the last two years. And Google support is a joke, paid or unpaid ;-)

Comment: You know, I have Google Apps running on one of my domains and it's OK. I might be the only one, but I'm not super excited about Gmail and the fact that if I let Google manage my email, there's almost nothing they don't have on me. I feel like Google is slowly taking over everything e.g. phone, computers, TVs, office productivity, and I'm the kind of person who doesn't like to keep all the eggs in one basket :)